# Comparing an index in a const char array to a char

Tags: c++, arrays, comparison, character

this is my first question on this website so, im sorry if i do something wrong.

My problem is that i have a program that is supposed to read in a text document full of letters, place each of the letters into a char array, and then find the amount of each letter in the array.

```
//i read in all the letters into the character array from my file and 
//display them to the screen to show that it works (and it does)

//here is the for loop to go through the array
// i am trying to check if the contents of the current index are C,S, or R.
//by comparing them to characters.

 ifstream inputFile;
        string path;
        int cloud,rain,sun = 0;
        char C = 'C';
        char R = 'R';
        char S = 'S';
        char array [3][30];
        cout << "The purpose of this program is to read in a text file and calculate a the number of days that were rainy." << endl;
        do{
            cout << "Please enter the full path to the included \" Summer.txt\" file included witht this program." << endl;
            cin >> path;
            inputFile.open(path);
            if(!inputFile){
                cout << "ERROR!!! No file was found at this location or there was a problem reading the file!" << endl;

            }
        }while(!inputFile);
        if(inputFile){
            cout << "Success! The file was found and read!" << endl;

            for(int r =0; r<3; r++){ //this is the loop to read in the text file
            for (int c = 0; c < 30; c++){
                inputFile >> array[r][c];
            }
        }
        for(int r =0; r<3; r++){ //this outputs the array to the screen
            for (int c = 0; c < 30; c++){
                cout << array[r][c] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;    
        }
        for(int r =0; r<3; r++){ //this is the loop to add up all the sun, cloud, and rain values.
            for (int c = 0; c < 30; c++){
                if(array[r][c] == C){
                    cloud++;
                }
                else if(array[r][c] == S){
                    sun++;
                }
                else if(array[r][c] == R){
                    rain++;
                }
            }   
        }
            cout << "Sun = " << sun << " rain = " << rain << " cloud = " << cloud << "." << endl;


        }

    }
```

The only problem is that when i output the values for sun rain and cloud, i get a random value for cloud.

is there a way to compare the contents of an index of a character array to a letter to get a boolean value?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: rxu he has a variable C = 'C', so that is valid. Although cloud and rain are unintialized which may explain random undefined behavior, the debugger could help.

Comment: It is too tedious to write a if statement for each letter. better use a loop to do that. Like set an array `char * letter = 'abcdefg...ABCDEFG'`
Then for each letter in the document, loop through the letter array to check if each of the letter in the letter array match the letter from the document.

Comment: `int cloud,rain,sun = 0;` only initializes `sun`. Sticking to one variable per declaration avoids that trap.

Answer (score 1):

`array[r][c] = S` should be replaced with `array[r][c] == S` and `array[r][c] = R` should be replaced with `array[r][c] == R.`

Also initialize cloud,sun and rain with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a 2 dimensional array, just use a single char array

```
char array [30]
```

now use 1 loop instead of 2 and a case/switch statement instead of the ifs:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
      switch (array[i])
      {
      case 'C':
      cloud++;
      break;
      case 'R':
      rain++;
      break;
      case 'S':
      sun++;
      break;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It seems that my boolean comparisons were ok, although when i declared
    int cloud,rain,sun = 0;
apparently, i was only declaring sun to equal 0.
changing this to assign one variable per declaration fixed my program!